# problem with my website layout, i gave each div containing slide of my slider a property position of value absolute and it hides elements following

Tags: javascript, html, css

i gave each div containing a slide of my slider a property position of value absolute and it hides elements following it.
basically i created a main tag with a section tag for the slider and another for the features section now because i gave `position: absolute` to the div with class **slide** the features section is invisible as it is hidden behind the slider section.
how can i fix this so that i can add other sections to my page and they appear properly following each other and not stacked or hiding behind each other like this.
please let me know if i don't get the real reason why this problem happened.

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderContainer .slide'),
  slideCount = slides.length,
  currentSlide = 1;

var paginationElement = document.createElement('ul');

paginationElement.setAttribute('id', 'paginationUl');

for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
  paginationItem = document.createElement('li');
  paginationItem.setAttribute('data-index', i);
  paginationElement.appendChild(paginationItem);
  // paginationItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
}

var indicators = document.getElementById('indicators');
indicators.appendChild(paginationElement);

var paginationUL = document.getElementById('paginationUl'),
  paginationBullets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#paginationUl li'));

for (var i = 0; i < paginationBullets.length; i++) {
  paginationBullets[i].onclick = function() {
    currentSlide = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
    console.log(currentSlide);
    checker();
  }
}

checker();

function checker() {
  removeActive();
  slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
  paginationBullets[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
}

function removeActive() {
  slides.forEach(function(slide) {
    slide.classList.remove('active');
  });

  paginationBullets.forEach(function(bullet) {
    bullet.classList.remove('active');
  });
}

var slideIndex = 0;
// showSlides();
function showSlides() {
  removeActive();
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slideCount) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
  paginationBullets[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

```css
.myMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* slider */

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  z-index: var(--z-normal);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.sliderContainer .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sliderControls .indicators ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  top: 35rem;
  left: 13rem;
  display: flex;
}

.sliderControls .indicators ul li {
  margin-right: var(--mg-3);
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  /* color: var(--light-color); */
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main class="myMain">
  <!-- slider -->
  <section class="sliderSection">
    <div class="sliderContainer">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <div class="slidecontent">
          <h1>START YOUR STARTUP WITH THIS TEMPLATE</h1>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="blueButton">Get Started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <div class="slidecontent">
          <h1>START YOUR STARTUP WITH THIS TEMPLATE</h1>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="blueButton">Get Started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <div class="slidecontent">
          <h1>START YOUR STARTUP WITH THIS TEMPLATE</h1>
          <button type="button" name="button" class="blueButton">Get Started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderControls">
      <span id="indicators" class="indicators">

          </span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- features -->
  <section class="featuresSection">
    <div class="featuresHeader">
      <h1>Our Awesome Features</h1>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="">

    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* slider */
.sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderContainer .slide {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  z-index: var(--z-normal);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
.sliderContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: i added your css to mine and still the problem not fixed

Comment: you have to remove `position: absolute;` in `.slide` class

Comment: ok the features section is visible now under the slide section but the slider is ruined as the slides became in a row and not stacked over each other like it should be and there is a scroll bar to view the slides @Fakt309